# XML deserialize getting null

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml, I need to serialize.

```
<Configuration>   
    <Configs>
        <tester>
            <test>gabc</test>
            <test>def</test>
        </tester>
    </Configs>
</Configuration>
```

This is the class used.

```
public class Configuration
{
   public tester Configs{ get; set; }
}

public class tester 
{
   // The web site name
   public string[] test{ get; set; }
}

Configuration obj = new Configuration();
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(SettingsFile, FileMode.Open);
obj = (Configuration)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
myFileStream.Close();
```

I am getting obj.configs.test as null.

How to get the values used in the test node?

Comment: Have you used the `[Serializable]` tag?

Comment: @ i just put [Serializable] tag in class .but still it is not getting the value

Comment: @user386258 - You dont need `[Serializable]`, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8926614/95573

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the [XmlArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx) and [XmlArrayItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx)

```
public class tester
{
   //The web site name
   [XmlArray("tester")]
   [XmlArrayItem("test")]
   public string[] test { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The xml config file should use `<string>` tag

So something like this:

```
<tester>
<string>gabc</string>
<string>def</string>
</tester>
```

Comment: i need to get the values in the string node.

Answer (score 0):

Your current classes serialize as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Configs>
    <test>
      <string>gabc</string>
      <string>def</string>
    </test>
  </Configs>
</Configuration>
```

I created this using the code:

```
 Configuration obj = new Configuration
                        {
                            Configs = new tester
                                          {
                                              test = new string[]
                                                         {
                                                             "gabc", "def"
                                                         }
                                          }
                        };

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));

string output;

using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    output = writer.ToString();
}
```

Use that code to modify the class so that it serializes the way you want to deserialize it. Serialization works two-way.

You can either implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface or use the xml range of attributes.